# Adding two Java 8 streams, or an extra element to a stream

Tags: java, concatenation, java-8, java-stream

I can add streams or extra elements, like this:

```
Stream stream = Stream.concat(stream1, Stream.concat(stream2, Stream.of(element));
```

And I can add new stuff as I go, like this:

```
Stream stream = Stream.concat(
                       Stream.concat(
                              stream1.filter(x -> x!=0), stream2)
                              .filter(x -> x!=1),
                                  Stream.of(element))
                                  .filter(x -> x!=2);
```

But this is ugly, because `concat` is static. If `concat` were an instance method, the above examples would be much easier to read:

```
 Stream stream = stream1.concat(stream2).concat(element);
```

And

```
 Stream stream = stream1
                 .filter(x -> x!=0)
                 .concat(stream2)
                 .filter(x -> x!=1)
                 .concat(element)
                 .filter(x -> x!=2);
```

My question is:

1) Is there any good reason why `concat` is static? Or is there some equivalent instance method I'm missing?

2) In any case, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: It looks like [thing were not always like this](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-November/006887.html), but I just can't find the reason why.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

If you add *static imports* for *Stream.concat* and *Stream.of*, the first example could be written as follows:

```
Stream<Foo> stream = concat(stream1, concat(stream2, of(element)));
```

Importing *static methods* with generic names can result in code that becomes difficult to read and maintain (*namespace pollution*). So, it might be better to create your own *static methods* with more meaningful names. However, for demonstration I will stick with this name.

```
public static <T> Stream<T> concat(Stream<? extends T> lhs, Stream<? extends T> rhs) {
    return Stream.concat(lhs, rhs);
}
public static <T> Stream<T> concat(Stream<? extends T> lhs, T rhs) {
    return Stream.concat(lhs, Stream.of(rhs));
}
```

With these two static methods (optionally in combination with static imports), the two examples could be written as follows:

```
Stream<Foo> stream = concat(stream1, concat(stream2, element));

Stream<Foo> stream = concat(
                         concat(stream1.filter(x -> x!=0), stream2).filter(x -> x!=1),
                         element)
                     .filter(x -> x!=2);
```

The code is now significantly shorter. However, I agree that the readability hasn't improved. So I have another solution.

---

In a lot of situations, *Collectors* can be used to *extend* the functionality of streams. With the two *Collectors* at the bottom, the two examples could be written as follows:

```
Stream<Foo> stream = stream1.collect(concat(stream2)).collect(concat(element));

Stream<Foo> stream = stream1
                     .filter(x -> x!=0)
                     .collect(concat(stream2))
                     .filter(x -> x!=1)
                     .collect(concat(element))
                     .filter(x -> x!=2);
```

The only difference between your desired syntax and the syntax above is, that you have to replace *concat(...)* with *collect(concat(...))*. The two static methods can be implemented as follows (optionally used in combination with static imports):

```
private static <T,A,R,S> Collector<T,?,S> combine(Collector<T,A,R> collector, Function<? super R, ? extends S> function) {
    return Collector.of(
        collector.supplier(),
        collector.accumulator(),
        collector.combiner(),
        collector.finisher().andThen(function));
}
public static <T> Collector<T,?,Stream<T>> concat(Stream<? extends T> other) {
    return combine(Collectors.toList(),
        list -> Stream.concat(list.stream(), other));
}
public static <T> Collector<T,?,Stream<T>> concat(T element) {
    return concat(Stream.of(element));
}
```

---

Of course there is a drawback with this solution that should be mentioned. *collect* is a final operation that consumes all elements of the stream. On top of that, the collector *concat* creates an intermediate *ArrayList* each time it is used in the chain. Both operations can have a significant impact on the behaviour of your program. However, if *readability* is more important than *performance*, it might still be a very helpful approach.

Comment: I don't find the `concat` collector much readable. It seems strange to a have single-parameter static method named like this, and also to use `collect` for concatenation.

Comment: @nosid, perhaps a slightly orthogonal question to this thread but why do you claim `It's a bad idea to import static methods with names`? I am genuinely interested - I find it makes the code more concise and readable and a lot of people I had asked thought the same. Care to provide some examples why that is generally bad?

Comment: @Quantum: What's the meaning of `compare(reverse(getType(42)), of(6 * 9).hashCode())`? Note that I didn't say that _static imports_ are a bad idea, but _static imports_ for generic names like `of` and `concat` are.

Comment: @nosid: Won't hovering over each statment in a modern IDE quickly reveal the meaning? At any rate, I think this could arguably be a personal preference statement at best, as I still see no technical reason why static imports for "generic" names is bad - unless you are using Notepad or VI(M) for programming in which case you have bigger problems.

Comment: I'm not gonna say that the Scala SDK is better, but... oops I said it.

Answer (score 176):

Unfortunately this answer is probably of little or no help whatsoever, but I did a forensics analysis of the Java Lambda Mailing list to see if I could find the cause of this design. This is what I found out.

**In the beginning there was an instance method for Stream.concat(Stream)**

In the mailing list I can clearly see the method was originally implemented as an instance method, as you can read in [this thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-September/005901.html) by Paul Sandoz, about the concat operation.

In it they discuss the issues that could arise from those cases in which the stream could be infinite and what concatenation would mean in those cases, but I do not think that was the reason for the modification.

You see in [this other thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-November/006735.html) that some early users of the JDK 8 questioned about the behavior of the concat instance method when used with null arguments.

This [other thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-October/006250.html) reveals, though, that the design of the concat method was under discussion.

**Refactored to Streams.concat(Stream,Stream)**

But without any explanation, suddenly, the methods were changed to static methods, as you can see in [this thread about combining streams](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-July/010660.html). This is perhaps the only mail thread that sheds a bit of light about this change, but it was not clear enough for me to determine the reason for the refactoring. But we can see they [did a commit](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-November/006887.html) in which they suggested to move the `concat` method out of `Stream` and into the helper class `Streams`.

**Refactored to Stream.concat(Stream,Stream)**

Later, [it was moved again](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-June/010249.html) from `Streams` to `Stream`, but yet again, no explanation for that.

So, bottom line, the reason for the design is not entirely clear for me and I could not find a good explanation. I guess you could still ask the question in the mailing list.

**Some Alternatives for Stream Concatenation**

This [other thread by Michael Hixson](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-July/010647.html) discusses/asks about other ways to combine/concat streams

> 1. To combine two streams, I should do this:
>
>    ```
>    Stream.concat(s1, s2)
>    ```
>
>    not this:
>
>    ```
>    Stream.of(s1, s2).flatMap(x -> x)
>    ```
>
>    ... right?
> 2. To combine more than two streams, I should do this:
>
>    ```
>    Stream.of(s1, s2, s3, ...).flatMap(x -> x)
>    ```
>
>    not this:
>
>    ```
>    Stream.of(s1, s2, s3, ...).reduce(Stream.empty(), Stream::concat)
>    ```
>
>    ... right?

Comment: +1 Nice research. And I will be using this as my Stream.concat taking varargs: `public static <T> Stream<T> concat(Stream<T>... streams) { return Stream.of(streams).reduce(Stream.empty(), Stream::concat);}`

Comment: Today i wrote my own concat version, and just after that I fund this topic.  Signature is slightly different but thanks to that its more generic;) for example you could merge Stream<Integer> and Stream<Double> to Stream<Number>.`@SafeVarargs private static <T> Stream<T> concat(Stream<? extends T>... streams) { return Stream.of(streams).reduce(Stream.empty(),Stream::concat).map(Function.identity());}`

Comment: @kant Why do you need a `Function.identity()` map? After all, it returns the same argument it receive. This should have no effect in the resulting stream. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to type it in your IDE? Without .map(identity()) you will get compilation error. I want to return Stream<T> but statement: `return Stream.of(streams).reduce(Stream.empty(),Stream::concat)` returns Stream<? extends T>.(Someting<T> is subtype of Something<? extends T>, not the other way, so it couldn't be cast) Additional `.map(identity())` cast <? extends T> to <T>. It happens thanks to mix of java 8 'target types' of method arguments and return types and signature of map() method. Actually it is Function.<T>identity().

Comment: @kant I just did without any problems. I guess your problem lies somewhere in your generics, not in the stream concatenation idiom.

Comment: Could you paste your code? Did your method return Stream<T> or Stream<? extends T> ?

Comment: @kant I don't see much point in doing `? extends T`, since you can use [capture conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10). At any rate, here's [my gist code snippet](https://gist.github.com/edalorzo/148c6e4f8f0c49d2d5f2) Let's continue the discussion in the Gist.

Answer (score 13):

Just do:

```
Stream.of(stream1, stream2, Stream.of(element)).flatMap(identity());
```

where `identity()` is a static import of `Function.identity()`.

Concatenating multiple streams into one stream is the same as flattening a stream.

However, unfortunately, for some reason there is no `flatten()` method on `Stream`, so you have to use `flatMap()` with the identity function.

Answer (score 12):

My [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library extends the functionality of Stream API. In particular it offers methods like [append](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#append-java.util.stream.Stream-) and [prepend](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#prepend-java.util.stream.Stream-) which solve this issue (internally they use `concat`). These methods can accept either another stream or collection or varargs array. Using my library your problem can be solved this way (note that `x != 0` look strange for non-primitive stream):

```
Stream<Integer> stream = StreamEx.of(stream1)
             .filter(x -> !x.equals(0))
             .append(stream2)
             .filter(x -> !x.equals(1))
             .append(element)
             .filter(x -> !x.equals(2));
```

By the way there's also a shortcut for your `filter` operation:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = StreamEx.of(stream1).without(0)
                                 .append(stream2).without(1)
                                 .append(element).without(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Guava's [`Streams`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html)`.`[`concat(Stream<? extends T>... streams)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream...-) method, which results in a flattened stream:

```
Stream stream = Streams.concat(stream1, stream2, Stream.of(element));
```

Comment: `Stream.of` is not meant to be static-imported.  It is read as "stream of" similar to `Optional.of` which is read as "optional of".  You wouldn't even be able to import both `Stream.of` and `Optional.of` in the same file.

Comment: @herman you're right - I modified my answer to focus on the brevity Guava brings, and leave the use (or misuse) of static imports to the discretion of the reader.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using 3rd Party Libraries [cyclops-react](https://github.com/aol/cyclops-react) has an extended Stream type that will allow you to do just that via the append / prepend operators.

Individual values, arrays, iterables, Streams or reactive-streams Publishers can be appended and prepended as instance methods.

```
Stream stream = ReactiveSeq.of(1,2)
                           .filter(x -> x!=0)
                           .append(ReactiveSeq.of(3,4))
                           .filter(x -> x!=1)
                           .append(5)
                           .filter(x -> x!=2);
```

[Disclosure I am the lead developer of cyclops-react]

Answer (score 0):

How about writing your own concat method?

```
public static <T> Stream<T> concat(Stream<? extends T> a, 
                                   Stream<? extends T> b, 
                                   Stream<? extends T>... args)
{
    Stream<T> concatenated = Stream.concat(a, b);
    for (Stream<? extends T> stream : args)
    {
        concatenated = Stream.concat(concatenated, stream);
    }
    return concatenated;
}
```

This at least makes your first example a lot more readable.

As @Legna pointed out, this could very fast result in a StackOverflowError due to nested calls to Stream::concat.

So here is another version that should fix the problem and looks quite neat:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> concat(final Stream<? extends T>... args)
{
    return args == null ? Stream.empty()
                        : Stream.of(args).flatMap(Function.identity());
}
```

Comment: Use caution when constructing streams from repeated concatenation. Accessing an element of a deeply concatenated stream can result in deep call chains, or even StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 0):

**At the end of the day I'm not interested in combining streams, but in obtaining the combined result of processing each element of all those streams.**

While combining streams might prove to be cumbersome (thus this thread), combining their processing results is fairly easy.

The key to solve is to create your own collector and ensure that the supplier function for the new collector returns the *same* collection every time (*not a new one*), the code below illustrates this approach.

```
package scratchpad;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CombineStreams {
    public CombineStreams() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        Collector<String, List<String>, List<String>> collector = Collector.of(
                () -> resultList,
                (list, item) -> {
                    list.add(item);
                },
                (llist, rlist) -> {
                    llist.addAll(rlist);
                    return llist;
                }
        );
        String searchString = "Wil";

        System.out.println("After processing first stream\n"
                + createFirstStream().filter(name -> name.contains(searchString)).collect(collector));
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("After processing second stream\n"
                + createSecondStream().filter(name -> name.contains(searchString)).collect(collector));
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("After processing third stream\n"
                + createThirdStream().filter(name -> name.contains(searchString)).collect(collector));
        System.out.println();

    }

    private static Stream<String> createFirstStream() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                "William Shakespeare",
                "Emily Dickinson",
                "H. P. Lovecraft",
                "Arthur Conan Doyle",
                "Leo Tolstoy",
                "Edgar Allan Poe",
                "Robert Ervin Howard",
                "Rabindranath Tagore",
                "Rudyard Kipling",
                "Seneca",
                "John Donne",
                "Sarah Williams",
                "Oscar Wilde",
                "Catullus",
                "Alfred Tennyson",
                "William Blake",
                "Charles Dickens",
                "John Keats",
                "Theodor Herzl"
        ).stream();
    }

    private static Stream<String> createSecondStream() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                "Percy Bysshe Shelley",
                "Ernest Hemingway",
                "Barack Obama",
                "Anton Chekhov",
                "Henry Wadsworth Longfellow",
                "Arthur Schopenhauer",
                "Jacob De Haas",
                "George Gordon Byron",
                "Jack London",
                "Robert Frost",
                "Abraham Lincoln",
                "O. Henry",
                "Ovid",
                "Robert Louis Stevenson",
                "John Masefield",
                "James Joyce",
                "Clark Ashton Smith",
                "Aristotle",
                "William Wordsworth",
                "Jane Austen"
        ).stream();
    }

    private static Stream<String> createThirdStream() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                "Niccolò Machiavelli",
                "Lewis Carroll",
                "Robert Burns",
                "Edgar Rice Burroughs",
                "Plato",
                "John Milton",
                "Ralph Waldo Emerson",
                "Margaret Thatcher",
                "Sylvie d'Avigdor",
                "Marcus Tullius Cicero",
                "Banjo Paterson",
                "Woodrow Wilson",
                "Walt Whitman",
                "Theodore Roosevelt",
                "Agatha Christie",
                "Ambrose Bierce",
                "Nikola Tesla",
                "Franz Kafka"
        ).stream();
    }
}
```