# What's the easiest way to combine multiple collections into a stream in Java?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Suppose I have multiple collections that I'd like to handle as a single stream. What's the easiest way to do this? Is there a utility class that can do this for me, or do I have to roll something myself?

In case my question isn't clear, this is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
Collection<Region> usaRegions;
Collection<Region> canadaRegions;
Collection<Region> mexicoRegions;
Stream<Region> northAmericanRegions = collect(usaRegions, canadaRegions, mexicoRegions);

public Stream<T> collect(T...) {
     /* What goes here? */
}
```

Comment: Yea its `java.util.stream.Stream.concat`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740464/adding-two-java-8-streams-or-an-extra-element-to-a-stream

Comment: Neat -- I didn't realize that `concat` existed! Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Alternately, you can use flatMap:

```
Stream<Region> = 
    Stream.of(usaRegions, canadaRegions, mexicoRegions)
          .flatMap(Collection::stream);
```